# How to sort simple SemVer version strings in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm quite a novice in databases and sqlalchemy.

I've got a model which looks like

```
class MySoftware(Base):

    __tablename__ = "my_software"
    version: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
```

where `version` looks like simple semver (e.g. `0.0.1`, `0.4.2`, `1.2.0`).

What I need is to perform simple sorting using this string, something like

```
db.scalars(select(MySoftware).order_by(asc("version"))).all()
```

I have read a lot about hybrid property and so many strange concepts for me that I can't find a way.

Can someone tell me how to achieve that?

Here is a minimal code to test it.

```
from pprint import pprint

from sqlalchemy import asc, create_engine, desc, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, Session, mapped_column


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class MySoftware(Base):

    __tablename__ = "my_software"
    version: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"MySoftware(version={self.version})"


# Create the engine and the session
engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
db = Session(engine)


version_list = ["0.10.1", "0.2.0", "3.0.1", "2.0.1"]
expected_version_list = ["0.2.1", "0.10.1", "2.0.1", "3.0.1"]

# Write contents
with db.begin():
    for v in version_list:
        db.add(MySoftware(version=v))

# Print the contents with version sorting
with engine.begin():

    s = select(MySoftware).order_by(asc("version"))

    pprint(db.scalars(s).all())

# Close the DB
db.close()
```

This returns

```py
[MySoftware(version=0.10.1),
 MySoftware(version=0.2.0),
 MySoftware(version=2.0.1),
 MySoftware(version=3.0.1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Python's built-in sorting could be more effective like:

```
sorted_versions = sorted(unsorted_versions, key=lambda v: semver_key(v.version))
```

To achieve a similar outcome using SQLite and SQLAlchemy would require to modify the table structure in the database and update the existing data to have separate columns for each part of the version string.

```
class MySoftware(Base):
    __tablename__ = "my_software"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    major = Column(Integer)
    minor = Column(Integer)
    patch = Column(Integer)
```

Then, you can sort the data directly within the SQL query using the ORDER BY clause with those columns.

```
sorted_versions = db.query(MySoftware).order_by(MySoftware.major, MySoftware.minor, MySoftware.patch).all()
```